# How to template static factory method?

Tags: c++, templates

how to template the below code? 
First, I have a Book as base:

```
class Book {
public:
    Book() {}
    ~Book() {}
}
```

Then ComputerBook:

```
class ComputerBook: public Book {
public:
    static ComputerBook* create() {
        return new ComputerBook();
    } 
private:
    ComputerBook ():Book() {}
}
```

Then PhoneBook:

```
class PhoneBook: public Book {
public:
    static PhoneBook* create() {
        return new PhoneBook();
    } 
private:
    PhoneBook():Book() {}
}
```

PhoneBook has two inheritances:

```
class PhoneBook1: public PhoneBook {
public:
    static PhoneBook1* create() {
        return new PhoneBook1();
    } 
private:
    PhoneBook1():PhoneBook() {}
}


class PhoneBook2: public PhoneBook {
public:
    static PhoneBook2* create() {
        return new PhoneBook2();
    } 
private:
    PhoneBook2():PhoneBook() {}
}
```

So that can merge ComputerBook and PhoneBook1,  PhoneBook2 into one with template?

Comment: `return new WhateverBook()`  Why don't you just use regular constructors?  Also, you don't need templates for this type of problem.  Inheritance and virtual functions are sufficient.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I am just thinking if it is possible to apply template to it.

Comment: I feel uncomfortable to turn it into template. It is unclear what you want to do with this code because it is contradictory and wrong in many ways. Applying template will make things worse.

Answer (score 2):

From what it looks like you are trying do do, you are making a static factory method called `create` for all of your books. You can templatize this method like this:

```
class Book {
public:
    Book() {}
    ~Book() {}
    template<typename T>
    static Book* create() {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

And then to make a phone book:

```
Book::create<PhoneBook1>();
```

Also make sure the constructors for each of the books are public, or friends of the `Book::create` static method.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with this answer. Could someone explain please?

Comment: This stupid factory function shouldn't exist in the first place.  You just make it worse by needlessly adding polymorphism on top.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is (probably) [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).  You define your method `create` in the base class where it is parametrized with the derived class which is a template parameter.  When inheriting from the template base you plug in the derived class and magically get the `create` function with the correct type.

I don't get why you have a private constructor or why you need this factory function at all though.

```
template < typename Derived >
class Book {
  friend Derived;
public:
  Book() {}
  ~Book() {}
  static Derived* create() {
    return new Derived{};
  }
};

class ComputerBook: public Book<ComputerBook> {
  // Make the base class a friend so we can access the private constructor
  friend class Book<ComputerBook>;
private:
  ComputerBook() : Book() {}
};

template < typename Derived >
class PhoneBook: public Book<Derived> {}; // no private constructor, no 'friend' needed

class PhoneBook1: public PhoneBook<PhoneBook1> {};
class PhoneBook2: public PhoneBook<PhoneBook2> {};

int main()
{
  auto cb = ComputerBook::create();
  auto pb1 = PhoneBook1::create();
  auto pb2 = PhoneBook2::create();
  delete cb;
  delete pb1;
  delete pb2;
}
```